# What can I do to improve the spacing in a Tikz tree?

Tags: tikz-trees

I finally managed to make a genealogy tree with Tikz, but there are some spaces that I can't figure out how to increase between nodes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,DIV=calc,headings=small{scrreprt}%,chapterprefix=true,numbers=noenddot
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures=Rare]{Minion Pro}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Consolas}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows,trees}



\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[draw, every node/.style={fill=Green, rectangle, rounded     corners},sibling distance=4cm,
level 6/.style={sibling distance=6cm}
]
\node {Maomé}
child {node (fatima) {Fátima}}
child {node (ali) {1. Ali} edge from parent [draw=none]
child {node {2. Hasan}}
child {node {3. Husayn} 
child {node {4. Ali Zaynu'l-Abidin}
child {node {Zayd} child {node [fill=green!30]{Zayditas}}}
child {node {5. Muhammad al-Baqir}
child {node {6. Jaafar al-Sadiq}
child {node {7. Ismail} child {node [fill=green!30] {Califado Ismaelita Fatímida do Egito}} child {node [fill=green!30]{Xiitas Ismaelitas}}}
child {node {7. Musa al-Kazim}
child {node {8. Ali al-Rida}
child {node {9. Muhammad al-Taqi}
child {node {10. Ali al-Hadi}
child {node {11. Hasan al-Askari}
child {node {12. Imam Mahdi}
child {node [fill=green!30] {Xiitas Duodecimais}}
}}}}}}}}}}};

\draw (fatima) -- (ali);
\end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I've tried, but I can't increase space between 7-8.
Is there any way I can get a more even space between those nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can supply `level distance=<larger value>` to the `child` that starts the eighth level. This will influence all levels that follow, so you will need to reset it using `level distance=<old value>` for the next child.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    draw,
    every node/.style={
        fill=green!70!black,
         rectangle,
        rounded corners
    },
    sibling distance=4cm,
    level distance=12mm,
    level 6/.style={
        sibling distance=6cm
    }
]
\node {Maomé}
child {node (fatima) {Fátima}}
child {node (ali) {1. Ali} edge from parent [draw=none]
child {node {2. Hasan}}
child {node {3. Husayn} 
child {node {4. Ali Zaynu'l-Abidin}
child {node {Zayd} child {node [fill=green!30]{Zayditas}}}
child {node {5. Muhammad al-Baqir}
child {node {6. Jaafar al-Sadiq}
child {node {7. Ismail} child {node [fill=green!30] {Califado Ismaelita Fatímida do Egito}} child {node [fill=green!30]{Xiitas Ismaelitas}}}
child {node {7. Musa al-Kazim}
child [level distance=24mm] {node {8. Ali al-Rida}
child [level distance=12mm] {node {9. Muhammad al-Taqi}
child {node {10. Ali al-Hadi}
child {node {11. Hasan al-Askari}
child {node {12. Imam Mahdi}
child {node [fill=green!30] {Xiitas Duodecimais}}
}}}}}}}}}}};

\draw (fatima) -- (ali);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

My answer is no direct answer to your question, but tries to provide a different approach to draw your tree. Here, this genealogy tree is made with the `genealogytree` package. The main differences to the original TikZ tree are that you can have more than one parent (usally two per family) and that the nodes are placed by an auto-layout algorithm which should give a nicer spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{genealogypicture}[processing=tcbox*,
  level size=5mm,
  node size from=5mm to 50mm,
  child distance=8mm,parent distance=8mm,further distance=8mm,
  box={size=fbox,boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,colback=Green,arc=3pt},
  edges={rounded=1mm,foreground={black,line width=0.3mm},background={white,line width=0.8mm}},
]
child{ g{Maomé}
  child{ g{Fátima} p{1. Ali} c{2. Hasan}
    child{ g{3. Husayn}
      child{ g{4. Ali Zaynu'l-Abidin}
        child{ g{Zayd} c[box={colback=green!30}]{Zayditas}
        }
        child{ g{5. Muhammad al-Baqir}
          child{ g{6. Jaafar al-Sadiq}
            child{ g{7. Ismail}
              c[box={colback=green!30}]{Califado Ismaelita Fatímida do Egito}
              c[box={colback=green!30}]{Xiitas Ismaelitas}
            }
            child{ g{7. Musa al-Kazim}
              child{ g{8. Ali al-Rida}
                child{ g{9. Muhammad al-Taqi}
                  child{ g{10. Ali al-Hadi}
                    child{ g{11. Hasan al-Askari}
                      child{ g{12. Imam Mahdi}
                        c[box={colback=green!30}]{Xiitas Duodecimais}
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
\end{genealogypicture}

\end{document}
```

For completeness: changing the level distance would be possible, but would affect all nodes of a level to keep the auto-layout algorithm working. Therefore, if there should be a generation jump between 7 and 8, you could insert an invisible linking node by

```
child{ g[phantom*,box={height=0mm}]{} ... }
```

which gives:

[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{genealogypicture}[processing=tcbox*,
  level size=5mm,
  node size from=5mm to 50mm,
  child distance=8mm,parent distance=8mm,further distance=8mm,
  box={size=fbox,boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,colback=Green,arc=3pt},
  edges={rounded=1mm,foreground={black,line width=0.3mm},background={white,line width=0.8mm}},
]
child{ g{Maomé}
  child{ g{Fátima} p{1. Ali} c{2. Hasan}
    child{ g{3. Husayn}
      child{ g{4. Ali Zaynu'l-Abidin}
        child{ g{Zayd} c[box={colback=green!30}]{Zayditas}
        }
        child{ g{5. Muhammad al-Baqir}
          child{ g{6. Jaafar al-Sadiq}
            child{ g{7. Ismail}
              c[box={colback=green!30}]{Califado Ismaelita Fatímida do Egito}
              c[box={colback=green!30}]{Xiitas Ismaelitas}
            }
            child{ g{7. Musa al-Kazim}
              child{ g[phantom*,box={height=0mm}]{} child{ g{8. Ali al-Rida}
                child{ g{9. Muhammad al-Taqi}
                  child{ g{10. Ali al-Hadi}
                    child{ g{11. Hasan al-Askari}
                      child{ g{12. Imam Mahdi}
                        c[box={colback=green!30}]{Xiitas Duodecimais}
}}}}}}}}}}}}}
\end{genealogypicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using the power of `forest`. This demonstrates how to use `fit=band` to get some separation between subtrees (separating the nodes at 7/8) and how to use `tikz` to draw the connection between siblings.

Two styles are defined to manage the numbering:

- `next` increments the number and numbers the node
- `again` numbers the node without increasing the number

The `pale green` style is used for the paler nodes.

[image: forest family]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
% use default fonts as I don't have proper Minion except for (pdf)TeX
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{mycount}
\begin{forest}
  pale green/.style={fill=green!30},
  next/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      TeX/.wrap pgfmath arg={\stepcounter{mycount}\def\mycounted{\themycount. ##1}}{content()},
      content/.expanded={\mycounted},
    }
  },
  again/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      TeX/.wrap pgfmath arg={\def\mycounted{\themycount. ##1}}{content()},
      content/.expanded={\mycounted},
    }
  },
  for tree={
    fill=Green,
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    drop shadow,
    edge=thick,
  }
  [Maomé
    [Fátima, tikz={\draw [thick] () -- (!n);}]
    [Ali, no edge, next
      [Hasan, next]
      [Husayn, next
        [Ali Zaynu'l-Abidin, next
          [Zayd
            [Zayditas, pale green]]
          [Muhammad al-Baqir, next
            [Jaafar al-Sadiq, next, for children={fit=band}
            [Ismail node, for children={pale green}, next
              [Califado Ismaelita Fatímida do Egito]
              [Xiitas Ismaelitas]
            ]
            [Musa al-Kazim, again
              [Ali al-Rida, next
                [Muhammad al-Taqi, next
                  [Ali al-Hadi, next
                    [Hasan al-Askari, next
                      [Imam Mahdi, next
                        [Xiitas Duodecimais, pale green]
  ]]]]]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```