# Good practice mindmap-like scheme

Tags: nodes, mindmaps, tikzpagenodes

I want to make a scheme like this:
[image]

I've started to work with `tikz`. Although I could make this in the way I'm doing it, I think it is not the correct way do make it.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a2paper,margin=0.2in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-base,pgf,tkz-euclide,tkz-linknodes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc,intersections,through,backgrounds, snakes,arrows.meta, decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,decorations.text,automata}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usetkzobj{all} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}

\parindent=0pt

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\bloklinks}[2]{
        \node[rounded corners=15pt,fill=#2,draw=black,thick,inner sep=0.5cm,text width= 8.9cm,align=center,minimum height=2cm,left]  at (#1) {\Huge{}};}

\newcommand{\hoofdblok}[3]{
    \node[rounded corners=15pt,fill=#2!30,draw=black,thick,inner sep=0.5cm,text width= 5cm,align=center,minimum height=4cm]  at (#1) {\Huge{#3}};}

\newcommand{\pijl}[3]{
    \node[single arrow,fill=#2,draw=black,thick,inner sep=0.4cm,minimum width= 5cm,minimum height=1cm]  at (#1) {\Large{#3}};}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmax=56, ymax=38]
    \tkzClip
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzDefPoints{24/19/M, 16/29/A, 34/29/B, 16/9/C, 34/9/D, 10/36/A1, 10/33/A2, 10/30/A3, 10/8.5/C1, 10/6/C2, 10/3.5/C3, 10/1/C4, 10/11/C5, 10/13.5/C6, 10/16/C7}  

        \node[rounded corners=15pt,fill=orange!70,draw=black,thick,inner sep=0.5cm,text width= 9cm,align=center,minimum height=2cm]  at (M) {\Large{Observerende en ori\"enterende \\[1em] Eerste graad}};

%%% hoofdblokken
\hoofdblok{A}{green}{}
\hoofdblok{B}{yellow}{}
\hoofdblok{C}{blue}{}
\hoofdblok{D}{red}{}

%%% nevenblokken

\bloklinks{C1}{blue!30}
\bloklinks{C2}{blue!30}
\bloklinks{C3}{blue!30}
\bloklinks{C4}{blue!30}

\bloklinks{C5}{blue!10}
\bloklinks{C6}{blue!10}
\bloklinks{C7}{blue!10}

\pijl{A2}{red!30}{\qquad \, \qquad \,}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in this:

[image]

So any hints to make it a more logical way (packages) would be appreciated...

Comment: Do you know the tikz mindmap library?

Comment: @samcarter yes... and there is the problem. the shapes are all circles, not what I want.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun and at best a starting point of an answer. I was wondering if one could use the forest library for the sub-trees. The answer is yes, to some extent. Whether or not the following is of any use for you, I don't know, but it might have some ingredients that are useful. I will also try to improve things later.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=20mm, right=20mm,
            foot=5mm, marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees,positioning}
\usepackage{forest}
% starting point: one of many cfr masterpieces: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251988/121799
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text} %  
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    outlined arrow width/.store in=\OutlinedArrowWidth,
    outlined arrow width=10pt,
    outlined arrow step/.store in=\OutlinedArrowStep,
    outlined arrow step=1pt,
    outlined arrow length/.store in=\OutlinedArrowLength,
    outlined arrow length=5pt,
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{outlined arrow}{initial}
{% initial arrow butt
\state{initial}[width=\OutlinedArrowStep,next state=cont] {
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{\OutlinedArrowStep}{\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\pgflinewidth}{\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\pgflinewidth}{-\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{-\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \pgfcoordinate{lastup}{\pgfpoint{1pt}{\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \pgfcoordinate{lastdown}{\pgfpoint{1pt}{-\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \xdef\marmotarrowstart{0}
  }
  \state{cont}[width=\OutlinedArrowStep]{
    \ifdim\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance>\OutlinedArrowLength% continue the outlined path
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{lastup}{center}}
     \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\OutlinedArrowStep}{\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
     \pgfcoordinate{lastup}{\pgfpoint{\OutlinedArrowStep}{\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{lastdown}{center}}
     \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\OutlinedArrowStep}{-\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
     \pgfcoordinate{lastdown}{\pgfpoint{\OutlinedArrowStep}{-\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \else
     \ifnum\marmotarrowstart=0% draw the arrow head
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{lastup}{center}}{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgflinewidth}{0}}}
     \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgflinewidth}{\OutlinedArrowWidth}}
     \pgflineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgflinewidth}{0}}}
     \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgflinewidth}{-\OutlinedArrowWidth}}
     \pgflineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{lastdown}{center}}{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgflinewidth}{0}}}
     \xdef\marmotarrowstart{1}
     \else
     \fi
    \fi%
  }
  \state{final}[width=5pt]
  { % perhaps unnecessary but doesn't hurt either
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}
%\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}
\tikzset{pale green/.style={fill=green!30,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},
  just green/.style={fill=green,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},   
}
\begin{forest}
  delay={where in content={grow}{for current/.pgfmath=content,content={}}{}},
  for tree={child anchor=east
  }
    [{grow=west},just green,name=tl
      [{grow=west},name=p1,no edge
        [,pale green]
        [,pale green]
        [,pale green]
        ]
      [{grow=west},name=p2,no edge
        [,just green]
        [,just green]
        [,just green]
      ]
    ]
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (tl) to[out=90,in=0] (p1); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| ~text},
  raise=-2.5pt,reverse path},decorate] (tl) to[out=90,in=0] (p1);
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (tl) to[out=-90,in=0] (p2); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| ~text},
  raise=-2.5pt,reverse path},decorate] (tl) to[out=-90,in=0] (p2);
\end{forest}
& 
\tikzset{pale yellow/.style={fill=yellow!30,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},
  just yellow/.style={fill=yellow,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},   }
\begin{forest}
  delay={where in content={grow}{for current/.pgfmath=content,content={}}{}},
  for tree={child anchor=west,grow=east 
  }
  [,just yellow,name=tr,right=1cm of tl
    [{grow=east},name=p3,no edge
      [,just yellow]
      [,just yellow]
      [,just yellow]
      ]
    [{grow=east},name=p4,no edge
      [,pale yellow]
      [,pale yellow]
    ] 
  ]
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (tr) to[out=-90,in=180] (p3); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| text~},
  raise=-2.5pt,text align=right},decorate] (tr) to[out=-90,in=180] (p3);
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (tr) to[out=90,in=180] (p4); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| text~},
  raise=-2.5pt,text align=right},decorate] (tr) to[out=90,in=180] (p4);
\end{forest}\\
%%%%%%% lower part
\tikzset{pale blue/.style={fill=blue!30,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},
  just blue/.style={fill=blue,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},   
}
\begin{forest}
  delay={where in content={grow}{for current/.pgfmath=content,content={}}{}},
  for tree={child anchor=east
  }
    [{grow=west},just blue,name=bl
      [{grow=west},name=p5,no edge
        [,pale blue]
        [,pale blue]
        [,pale blue]
        ]
      [{grow=west},name=p6,no edge
        [,just blue]
        [,just blue]
        [,just blue]
        [,just blue]
      ]
    ]
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (bl) to[out=90,in=0] (p5); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| ~text},
  raise=-2.5pt,reverse path},decorate] (bl) to[out=90,in=0] (p5);
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (bl) to[out=-90,in=0] (p6); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| ~text},
  raise=-2.5pt,reverse path},decorate] (bl) to[out=-90,in=0] (p6);
\end{forest}
& 
\tikzset{pale red/.style={fill=red!30,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},
  just red/.style={fill=red,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},   }
\begin{forest}
  delay={where in content={grow}{for current/.pgfmath=content,content={}}{}},
  for tree={child anchor=west,grow=east 
  }
  [,just red,name=br,right=1cm of bl
    [{grow=east},name=p7,no edge
      [,pale red]
      [,pale red]
      [,pale red]
      ]
    [{grow=east},name=p8,no edge
      [,just red]
      [,just red]
      [,just red]
    ] 
  ]
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (br) to[out=-90,in=180] (p7); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| text~},
  raise=-2.5pt,text align=right},decorate] (br) to[out=-90,in=180] (p7);
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (br) to[out=90,in=180] (p8); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| text~},
  raise=-2.5pt,text align=right},decorate] (br) to[out=90,in=180] (p8);
\end{forest}\\
\end{tabular}
%
% \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
% \node[fill=gray,drop shadow,rounded corners,draw,text width=3cm,minimum
% height=2cm] at (barycentric cs:tl=0.25,tr=0.25,bl=0.25,br=0.25)    {XXX};
% \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are some things that I do not understand, some of them associated to the fact that the snippet goes berserk once I try using overlays. So it might be that the whole approach is a dead end.

**UPDATE**: Certainly not a final answer, but switching gears and trying to do all inside a single forest environment seems to work, at least to some extent. This might be the cleaner option, but clearly there are several flaws in this version.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=20mm, right=20mm,
            foot=5mm, marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees,positioning}
\usepackage{forest}
% starting point: one of many cfr masterpieces: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251988/121799
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text} %  
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    outlined arrow width/.store in=\OutlinedArrowWidth,
    outlined arrow width=10pt,
    outlined arrow step/.store in=\OutlinedArrowStep,
    outlined arrow step=1pt,
    outlined arrow length/.store in=\OutlinedArrowLength,
    outlined arrow length=5pt,
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{outlined arrow}{initial}
{% initial arrow butt
\state{initial}[width=\OutlinedArrowStep,next state=cont] {
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{\OutlinedArrowStep}{\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\pgflinewidth}{\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\pgflinewidth}{-\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{-\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \pgfcoordinate{lastup}{\pgfpoint{1pt}{\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \pgfcoordinate{lastdown}{\pgfpoint{1pt}{-\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \xdef\marmotarrowstart{0}
  }
  \state{cont}[width=\OutlinedArrowStep]{
    \ifdim\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance>\OutlinedArrowLength% continue the outlined path
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{lastup}{center}}
     \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\OutlinedArrowStep}{\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
     \pgfcoordinate{lastup}{\pgfpoint{\OutlinedArrowStep}{\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{lastdown}{center}}
     \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\OutlinedArrowStep}{-\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
     \pgfcoordinate{lastdown}{\pgfpoint{\OutlinedArrowStep}{-\OutlinedArrowWidth/2}}
    \else
     \ifnum\marmotarrowstart=0% draw the arrow head
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{lastup}{center}}{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgflinewidth}{0}}}
     \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgflinewidth}{\OutlinedArrowWidth}}
     \pgflineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgflinewidth}{0}}}
     \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgflinewidth}{-\OutlinedArrowWidth}}
     \pgflineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{lastdown}{center}}{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgflinewidth}{0}}}
     \xdef\marmotarrowstart{1}
     \else
     \fi
    \fi%
  }
  \state{final}[width=5pt]
  { % perhaps unnecessary but doesn't hurt either
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}
%\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{pale green/.style={fill=green!30,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},
  just green/.style={fill=green,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},   
}
\tikzset{pale yellow/.style={fill=yellow!30,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},
  just yellow/.style={fill=yellow,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},   }
\tikzset{pale blue/.style={fill=blue!30,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},
  just blue/.style={fill=blue,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},   }
\tikzset{pale red/.style={fill=red!30,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},
  just red/.style={fill=red,rounded corners,
    drop shadow,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=6mm,},   }

\begin{forest}
  delay={where in content={grow}{for current/.pgfmath=content,content={}}{}},
  for tree={%child anchor=east,
  grow=south,no edge
  }
  [,phantom
% top left  
   [{grow=north west}
    [{grow=west},just green,name=tl
      [{grow=west},name=tl1
        [,pale green]
        [,pale green]
        [,pale green]
        ]
      [{grow=west},name=tl2
        [,just green]
        [,just green]
        [,just green]
      ]
     ] 
    ]
% bottom left  
 [,name=center
  [
   [{grow=west}
    [{grow=west},just blue,name=bl,xshift=1mm
      [{grow=west},name=bl1
        [,pale blue]
        [,pale blue]
        [,pale blue]
        ]
      [{grow=west},name=bl2
        [,just blue]
        [,just blue]
        [,just blue]
      ]
     ] 
    ]
    ]
%bottom right   
   [
   [{grow=east}
    [{grow=east},just red,name=br,xshift=-1mm
      [{grow=east},name=br1
        [,pale red]
        [,pale red]
        [,pale red]
        ]
      [{grow=east},name=br2
        [,just red]
        [,just red]
        [,just red]
      ]
    ]
   ]    
  ]
  ] 
% top right 
  [,phantom] 
   [{grow=north east} 
    [{grow=east},just yellow,name=tr
      [{grow=east},name=tr1
        [,pale yellow]
        [,pale yellow]
        [,pale yellow]
        ]
      [{grow=east},name=tr2
        [,just yellow]
        [,just yellow]
        [,just yellow]
      ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
\node[fill=gray,text width=3cm,align=center,minimum height=3cm,rounded corners,draw,drop
shadow] at ([yshift=-1.1cm]center){whatever}; % ugly : yshift by hand
%
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (tl) to[out=90,in=0] (tl1); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| ~text},
  raise=-2.5pt,reverse path},decorate] (tl) to[out=90,in=0] (tl1);
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (tl) to[out=-90,in=0] (tl2); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| ~text},
  raise=-2.5pt,reverse path},decorate] (tl) to[out=-90,in=0] (tl2);
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (bl) to[out=90,in=0] (bl1); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| ~text},
  raise=-2.5pt,reverse path},decorate] (bl) to[out=90,in=0] (bl1);
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (bl) to[out=-90,in=0] (bl2); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| ~text},
  raise=-2.5pt,reverse path},decorate] (bl) to[out=-90,in=0] (bl2);
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (tr) to[out=-90,in=180] (tr1); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| text~},
  raise=-2.5pt,text align=right},decorate] (tr) to[out=-90,in=180] (tr1);
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (tr) to[out=90,in=180] (tr2); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| text~},
  raise=-2.5pt,text align=right},decorate] (tr) to[out=90,in=180] (tr2);
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (br) to[out=-90,in=180] (br1); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| text~},
  raise=-2.5pt,text align=right},decorate] (br) to[out=-90,in=180] (br1);
\draw[decoration={outlined arrow},decorate] (br) to[out=90,in=180] (br2); 
\fill[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily\small| text~},
  raise=-2.5pt,text align=right},decorate] (br) to[out=90,in=180] (br2);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]